# Finding path of static system libraries in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, openssl, ld

I am compiling a package that links against the OpenSSL static libraries `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` which are included with `libssl-dev` in Debian/Ubuntu. However the actual location of these files depends on the architecture and distribution at hand.

Is there some sort of method or environment variable that I can use in the Makefile to give the linker the correct path to the system directory with static libraries? Currently I am using:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -L/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/ -lssl -lcrypto
```

However this gives a bunch of warnings if these dirs do not exist, and might still not generally work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are sure, that your users are using aptitude as package manager, that is default for Debian/Ubuntu, than you can use apt-file to locate libraries.

```
$ apt-file update
$ LIBSSL_PATH=`apt-file list libssl-dev | grep libssl.a | awk '{ print $2 }'`
$ LIBCRYPTO_PATH=`apt-file list libssl-dev | grep libcrypto.a | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

Next you may use them. Say on my machine:

```
$ echo $LIBSSL_PATH
/usr/lib/libssl.a
```

I known no other way and doubt if any exists.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same for my ubuntu machine.
I was able to find the library by using the following command.

```
sudo find libssl.a / | grep libssl.a
```

The default location for ubuntu is.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
```